# I installed the 'raster' package but couldn't load its library in R. What is the problem here, and how could we resolve this?

Tags: r, geospatial

```
install.packages("raster")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/hp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ (as
> ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
> binary source needs_compilation raster 3.3-13  3.4-5              TRUE
>
> Binaries will be installed trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/raster_3.3-13.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 3555261 bytes (3.4 MB)
> downloaded 3.4 MB
>
> package ‘raster’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsHDNOk\downloaded_packages

```
library(raster)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in inDL(x,
> as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):  unable to load shared
> object
> 'C:/Users/hp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/raster/libs/x64/raster.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found. In
> addition: Warning message: package ‘raster’ was built under R version
> 4.0.3

Comment: Please show the result of `.libPaths()`

Comment: > .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/hp/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library"

Comment: The installation runs through without error?

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong while installing but can't load its library. And there is also this popup saying: The procedure entry point EXTPTR_PTR could not be located in the dynamic link library--- C:\Users\hp\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\raster\libs\×64\raster.dll.

Comment: Please provide information in detail - to each command and - its corresponding output and update your question.

Comment: I had only used the above two commands. There was an error in the dynamic link library (Windows OS). I had to uninstall R/R-Studio, and it is working fine now. Thanks for your interest.